# nearest neighbour algoritm implentation for 25k store addresses to be matched with 76k points in python

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to find a solution to the nearest neighbour algorithm.
I have a list o stores (about 25000) with coordinates and a list of exagon that belong to different bordered cities i cover with deliveries described by centroid coordinates and and hexagon polygon.

I need to tell to what hexagon each address belong,
I can find the brute force solution but it need about 2 days of calculation and I am interested in finding a fast solution to run frequently if city coverages have to change.

data of stores:

```
    INDIRIZZO_COMPLETO  latitude    longitude   COORDINATE_EXTRACTION_DETAIL
0   LUNGOMARE LUIGI RIZZO 1, 92010 LAMPEDUSA E LIN...   35.497965   12.607482   from original address
1   VIA TERRANOVA 71, 92010 LAMPEDUSA E LINOSA (AG...   35.506421   12.610504   from original address
2   VIALE PAPA PIO XII 107/109, 00036 PALESTRINA (...   35.551062   12.320357   from zipcode: 36 Italy
3   VIA ROMA 82, 96010 PORTOPALO DI CAPO PASSERO (...   36.682967   15.133651   from original address
4   CONTRADA PIANETTI SNC, 96018 PACHINO (SR), SIC...   36.700497   15.073600   from zipcode: 96018 Italy
```

data of exagon:

```
city_code   Polygon latitude    longitude
0   SCN POLYGON ((10.63303663611384 44.59771368472511,...   44.597003   10.635361
1   SCN POLYGON ((10.706225086720105 44.58751732975397...   44.586805   10.708550
2   BAR POLYGON ((16.939176495419776 41.09659615583256...   41.095711   16.941403
3   BAR POLYGON ((16.925717571722554 41.10755391076213...   41.106669   16.927944
4   BAR POLYGON ((16.89992580762363 41.067339007464646...   41.066454   16.902151
```

I implemented a solution using this:

```
tree = BallTree(np.deg2rad(df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values), metric='haversine')

distances, indices = tree.query(np.deg2rad(np.c_[query_lats, query_lons]), k = 5)

r_km = 6371 # multiplier to convert to km (from unit distance)
for name, d, ind in zip(df_other['INDIRIZZO_COMPLETO'], distances, indices):
  print(f"INDIRIZZO_COMPLETO {name} closest matches:")
  for i, index in enumerate(ind):
    print(f"\t{df['city_code'][index]} with distance {d[i]*r_km:.4f} km")
    list_data = (name, df['city_code'][index], d[i]*r_km)
    append_list_as_row(file_name_2, list_data)
```

with quite good response for some zone and totally wrong a lot of others

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use geopandas.sjoin to efficiently assign points to polygons:

```py
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(
        df.longitude, df.latitude
    ),
)
joined = geopandas.sjoin(
    gdf,
    other_df,
    how="left",
    predicate="intersects",
)
```